# React-native-maps app crashes on Android 6.0.1 when run in release version but works on dev version

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

React native app **works in dev mode** but when I build the APK and run it in release mode on Android 6.0.1 it crashes due to the use of react-native-maps mapview. It sometimes gives an out of memory exception and sometims and SIGSEGV exception (see images below for stack trace). Important to know is that this works on dev mode in Android 6.0.1 on a Samsung Galaxy S7 but doesn't if I build a release mode. It works both on dev and release when run on an Android 8 or Android 9 device.

Tried to change my build gradle, remove specific map properties, build 32 bit version.

```
implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-location'
}
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
```

[Out of memory error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Oohg.jpg) -
[Strange error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fw9KD.png)

**ENVIRONMENT:**

- react-native: 0.59.4
- react: 16.6.3
- react-native-maps: 0.24.0
- Samsung Galaxy S7 Android 6.0.1

Comment: Could you attach some logat about the crash? If you haven't logged yet, connect your phone with your PC and connect android studio to see what could be failing?

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17431378/56034683-535a1b80-5d28-11e9-811d-2fcf80e5f4f5.png there you go. Sometimes, I get an out of memory error

Comment: Wow, isn't more error like exceptions from java? Anyway, are you ensuring that you have GPS and WIFI enabled in the device?

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai yeah thats it... and GPS is enabled and my app is allowed to check it (asking permission on splash screen and checked in the settings)

Comment: What stranger thing.. I would like to help you but I will need more info about the logcat. If you catch the moment of the crash, take another screenshot and post it here. It would be awesome if you post it in the question instead of here in the comment to able the other people see what could be happening

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai I put both errors as an image in the original question.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/590#issuecomment-279507074

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai unfortunatly, still getting the out of memory exception. Which is super strange since it works on react-native run-android but doesnt when I put the --variant=release flag behind it.

Comment: what if you build the app and install the .apk in your smartphone?

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai Same happens, I also downloaded it from the appstore but fails aswell.

Comment: I don't know what we could do, it scapes my understanding. Anyway, I hope you find the fix to that problem. Get luck!

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai Thanks anyway!